# Retrofit: Remove Content-Length header

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using Retrofit (version 2.9.0) to make request to the API server. This library by default adds `Content-Length` header to the request. Unfortunately server rejects this header for "security" purposes - I don't have affect to this. Is it possible to remove this header from request using Retrofit? Or do I have to create my own rest api client?

`removeHeader("Content-Length")` function of `Request.Builder` does not works, it looks like library adds it after request build. I can change value of this header calling `addHeader("Content-Length", "any-value")` but it's not what I need.

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder().apply {
            removeHeader("Content-Length") // Doesn't works
        }
        
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }
```

**#Edit**

For the people below. I already confirmed that with logging interceptor, so there is no need to write useless code here. And the fuction above is from... `Interceptor` ... but If you want and that can help:

**HeaderInterceptor**

```
class HeaderInterceptor() : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder().apply {
            removeHeader("Content-Length") // Doesn't works
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }
}
```

**Building Retrofit Client**

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesUserApi(headerInterceptor: HeaderInterceptor): UsersApi {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            addInterceptor(tokenInterceptor)
            addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        }.build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_USERS_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client).build()
            .create(UsersApi::class.java)
    }
```

**API Interface**

```
interface UsersApi {

    @POST("/api/auth/login")
    suspend fun login(@Body user: LoginRequest): Response<LoginResponse>
}
```

`LoginRequest` is simple POJO data class which holds login/password fields and `LoginResponse` is data returned by server.

**Logcat**

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST https://this_is_api_server.com/api/auth/login
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 60
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"device_type":"ANDROID","email":"admin","password":"admin"}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (60-byte body)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

**Event log from client**

I masked domain name and IP addresses with XXX.

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [2 ms] callStart: Request{method=POST, url=https://securedapiserver.com/api/auth/v1/loginByEmail, tags={class retrofit2.Invocation=package.name.api.UsersApi.login() [LoginRequest(device_type=ANDROID, email=test, password=test)]}}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> POST https://securedapiserver.com/api/auth/v1/loginByEmail
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 58
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"device_type":"ANDROID","email":"test","password":"test"}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END POST (58-byte body)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [98 ms] proxySelectStart: https://securedapiserver.com/
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [103 ms] proxySelectEnd: [DIRECT]
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [105 ms] dnsStart: securedapiserver.com
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [158 ms] dnsEnd: [securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX, securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX]
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [175 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [176 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [178 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [179 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [180 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [181 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [182 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [183 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [184 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [184 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [186 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [187 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [188 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [189 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [191 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [194 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [196 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [197 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [198 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [199 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [201 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [201 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [202 ms] connectStart: securedapiserver.com/XXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:443 DIRECT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [203 ms] connectFailed: null java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/System.out: [java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted), java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)]
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [212 ms] callFailed: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
E/NetworkCall: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

** EDIT 2021-03-19 **

Thanks to @Yuri Schimke the problem was solved. I had to completely remove emulator and create new one. It looks like there was problem with http stack?

Comment: What is your Retrofit request? I do not see where Retrofit is adding that header. OkHttp may be adding that header, particularly if your request is using something like `Multipart`.

Comment: @CommonsWare please check my updated post

Comment: Try switching the `headerInterceptor` to be [a network interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/#network-interceptors).

Comment: @CommonsWare doesn't works. Even worse, because with a network interceptor I can't change value of Content-Length header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)` looks like a client side error. The Android OS blocking you app from sending network requests.  You should check you have granted INTERNET permissions to your app. You probably have an exception with stacktrace that you could include that would confirm this, without seeing that we are generally guessing here.

To confirm the headers look at adding an OkHttp network interceptor and making the change there if needed https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

Or just start with looking at using a Logging interceptor to confirm your suspicions https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(Level.HEADERS);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .addInterceptor(logging)
  .build();
```

To confirm whether this is a client side socket error, or a valid 400 response from the server you should use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/66398516/1542667 to log connection events.

```
[0 ms] callStart: Request{method=GET, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
[11 ms] proxySelectStart: https://httpbin.org/
[12 ms] proxySelectEnd: [DIRECT]
[12 ms] dnsStart: httpbin.org
[55 ms] dnsEnd: [httpbin.org/54.147.165.197, httpbin.org/34.231.30.52, httpbin.org/54.91.118.50, httpbin.org/18.214.80.1, httpbin.org/54.166.163.67, httpbin.org/34.199.75.4]
[62 ms] connectStart: httpbin.org/54.147.165.197:443 DIRECT
[176 ms] secureConnectStart
[747 ms] secureConnectEnd: Handshake{tlsVersion=TLS_1_2 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 peerCertificates=[CN=httpbin.org, CN=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, O=Amazon, C=US, CN=Amazon Root CA 1, O=Amazon, C=US] localCertificates=[]}
[765 ms] connectEnd: h2
[767 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{httpbin.org:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=httpbin.org/54.147.165.197:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=h2}
[775 ms] requestHeadersStart
[783 ms] requestHeadersEnd
[993 ms] responseHeadersStart
[994 ms] responseHeadersEnd: Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://httpbin.org/get}
[999 ms] responseBodyStart
[999 ms] responseBodyEnd: byteCount=267
[999 ms] connectionReleased
[1000 ms] callEnd
```

Comment: Sure.  You seem frustrated in your edit "useless code", but please consider the effort of people answering and whether examples your provide in your question are complete or leave a lot of assumptions.

Comment: Maybe you are right I was little frustrated because of I'm dealing with this for some days - sorry. But you are not right, this is not client side error. I asked API owner and he said that for "security purposes" (as I mentioned in my first post) they check headers and if it contains Content-Length they simple return 400 error. I don't know why they decided to do that, but I don't have affect to this. It looks like I have to write my own client if it's impossible to remove Content-Length header...

Comment: But you have committed that completely from the example you provided above.  A 400 error from the server would be returned as such.  This is a socket error before it connects to remote server.

Comment: I added some steps above for logging connection events also. Hopefully you don't have to write your own clients there are many alternative clients available if OkHttp doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added log to the first post. I also checked this with POSTMAN. I send request without Content-Length header and then I get 200 response with content and after that I added Content-Length header which generated a 400 error.

Comment: Sure, but the logs above aren't 400 responses, they are client side socket failures.

Comment: Well.. thanks to you I solved the problem. I realised that MUST be client side error. I had to completely remove emulator... I created new one and It worked... I still don't know why server rejects request when I send them with Postman with Content-Length and works without it but it doesn't matter at this moment. Thank you so much, you saved my life =) P.S. I have to wait 12 hours untill I can give you bounty :)