# OkHTTP Basic Authentication does nothing

Tags: android, webclient, okhttp

Here is the following code, I try to do a basic auth with okhttp by following some example. The normal HTTP request (commented out) works fine so it's not a network issue or anything like that. The main fetch code which would try to authenticate does not try to connect to the webserver at all. There is nothing in the webservers log, I don't get anything if I checking on port 80 with tcpdump.

Any idea from those who are using OkHTTP?

```
package com.example.webclient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Authenticator;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.Route;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private OkHttpClient client;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // works
   // client = new OkHttpClient();
   // run("http://192.168.1.1/old");

    //does not work
    String url = "http://192.168.1.1/new";

    try {
      fetch(url, "user", "pass");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }



  }

  private void run(String url) {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      @Override
      public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response){
        String url = response.body().toString();
        //your code here
      }
    });
  }


  public static Response fetch(String url, String username, String password) throws Exception {

    OkHttpClient httpClient = createAuthenticatedClient(username, password);
    // execute request
    return doRequest(httpClient, url);

  }

  private static OkHttpClient createAuthenticatedClient(final String username,
                                                        final String password) {
    // build client with authentication information.
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().authenticator(new Authenticator() {
      public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
        if (responseCount(response) >= 3) {
          return null;
        }
        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
      }
    }).build();
    return httpClient;
  }

  private static Response doRequest(OkHttpClient httpClient, String anyURL) throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(anyURL).build();
    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
      throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    }
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
    return response;
  }

  private static int responseCount(Response response) {
    int result = 1;
    while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
      result++;
    }
    return result;
  }


}
```

Comment: Turn on event logging so you can see the initial request and retries https://stackoverflow.com/a/66398516/1542667

Comment: This line `System.out.println(response.body().string());` will consume the body before your app sees it.

Comment: In general, it would be helpful to specify the version of OkHTTP API you are using

Comment: Yuri's comment is correct, response body's can only be consumed once. https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response/

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying network operation in Application's main thread (in onCreate) . Before call to fetch method you should permit StrictMode ThreadPolicy for developing/debugging purpose.

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // works
   //  client = new OkHttpClient();
   //  run("http://192.168.1.1/old");

    //does not work
    String url = "http://192.168.1.1/new";
    try {
        fetch(url, "user", "pass");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```